# Primality testing (deterministic vs. non-deterministic)

Tags: algorithm-design, prime-numbers

I noticed that non-deterministic primality testing algorithms are more commonly used in practice while there is a deterministic algorithm e.g., AKS which runs in polynomial time? I am right? if so, then why? is there any drawbacks of using AKS?

Thanks,

Comment: Compared to probabilistic algorithms AKS is horribly inefficient.

Comment: Because asymptotic complexity isn't the whole story.

Comment: Thanks Maeher and Thomas, could you please clarify the answer in a bit more details? Thanks

Comment: On real hardware all algorithms are probabilistic and something like $2^{-200}$ is certainly smaller than the probability of your hardware messing up the computation. So deterministic algorithms don't really offer a practical advantage.

Comment: @CodesInChaos This argument in general is true if and only if an attacker cannot control the inputs to the algorithm (e.g. in an attempt to make it fail), fortunately most modern primality tests (including Rabin-Miller) are immune to this to an arbitrary number of rounds.

Comment: Not only is it more likely your computer will screw things up, it's around as likely as the session key being used simply being all 0s or 1s due to pure bad luck! @Thomas It's immune as long as the witnesses are not controlled by the attacker.

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is that AKS horribly inefficient in the real world.
Even the asymptotic complexity is orders of magnitudes higher than the one of probabilistic algorithms. [Here](http://cs.anu.edu.au/student/comp4600/lectures/comp4600_primality.pdf) is a comparison of AKS with Rabin-Miller and other probabilistic algorithms.
The following table illustrates the problem nicely (The tested number was $10^{
100}
+ 267$:

[image: runtime of primality tests]

Comment: It'd be useful to add a column that states the probability of being wrong.

Comment: I wonder how [this Las Vegas algorithm](http://cr.yp.to/primetests/quartic-20060914-ams.pdf) would compare to ECPP. $\:$

Comment: To clarify this table (what does the middle column mean): AKS and ECPP are deterministic, while Rabin Miller is probabilistic so it requires a "numer of trials" input. ECPP is (practically/empirically) the fastest of the two deterministic algos, but (probabilistic) Rabin-Miller is still very widely used in crypto because it is so simple/fast and you can increase the number of trials as much as you want to be confident in the test result.

Comment: @CodesInChaos The probabilities of a false negative are $4^{-1}$, $4^{-10}$, $4^{-100}$, $0$, and $0$, respectively.